# Kendo UI TabStrip in relative position div

Tags: kendo-ui

I have some troubles with TabStrip in relative position div, tabs doesn't switch, if I use them in the way as:

```
<div style="position: relative">
   <div style="padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px; position: absolute">
      <div id="myTabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="k-state-active">item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <input type="text" value="" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100px" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" value="" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100px" />
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myTabs").kendoTabStrip();
    }
</script>
```

May be some one faced with such problem, or there is a mistake in my example ?

Answer (score 1):

If document.ready is removed, the code works fine. Please check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9Qf/20/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#myTabs").kendoTabStrip();

</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work